# Cross-platform app to play sounds on button press

Tags: android, ios

I am working on a project where I need to make an Android and iOS app. The App is very simple and only contains buttons with labels on them. When you push a button, the App is going to play a sound. That is the easy part now comes my question and what I need help with. The User wants to be able to have a kind of control admin panel were he can change the sounds and the labels on the buttons. How can I do this easily?

I thought it would be best to make a web page with a kind of form were the user chooses the sounds and labels. What is the best way to connect the web page and the apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the application is that simple use the web technology - the [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch) is very popular web (HTML(5)/JavaScript/CSS3) framework for that. The advantage of the Sencha Touch is the application optimization for mobile phone browsers (screen sizes, rotation, touch events, UI elements).

When you will be done with the Sencha Touch you can use the [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) - this is a wrapper for web content written in native language (Java on Android, Objective-C on iPhone, etc.).

PhoneGap is using the embedded web view component to render the web content you prepare with use of the Sencha Touch. It creates the impression that your application is native one., so you can launch it outside of web browser.

This is of course not the perfect solution and has many (really many) drawbacks, but for your case it might be sufficient and is worth to check.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Phonegap http://phonegap.com/  you can create a web app and run it on a number of different devices.